# In Laravel, what are the benefits of using redis and socket.io over pusher other than it's free?

Tags: laravel, sockets, redis, socket.io, pusher

Pusher seems like a nice package, but recently a friend programmer of mine wanted me to try out socket.io and redis because it doesn't cost anything. Other than not costing anything, is there any particular reason to use socket.io+redis? I really don't want to use the combo if the only benefit I get out of it is free, especially since there's less documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Laravel broadcasting backend, the primary difference between Pusher and Redis/Socket.IO is that Pusher is a hosted service, but with Redis or Socket.IO, you will need to deploy the service somewhere yourself. This means you must pay for the resources the process consumes (e.g. EC2 instances), you will need to maintain the service when it breaks, and scale the service when your app becomes popular. On the other hand, Redis/Socket.IO could be more customisable if Pusher doesn't fit your needs.

(I could be biased: I work for Pusher!)

Comment: Hey, thanks James, you guys are awesome at Pusher! Love you guys! :)

Comment: @SimonSuh happy to help :)